# How to use loadRecord to populate form in Sencha Touch 1

Tags: sencha-touch

I am new to Sencha touch and have run into a simple problem that I can not seem to figure out. I have stripped down my code to make it as simple as possible. I am trying to load data to my simple form from a store and the data will not load. Can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong. Here is the code

```
Ext.setup({

    onReady: function() {

     var projectModel = Ext.regModel('projModel', {
          fields: [
                   {name: 'project_id', type: 'string'},
                   {name: 'project_name', type: 'string'}                                      
          ]
     });      

     var projectStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
          model  : 'projModel',
          storeId: 'projStore',
          autoLoad: true,
          proxy: {
              type: 'ajax',
              url: 'project.json',

              reader: {
                  type: 'json'
              }
          }  
     });

     var projectForm = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
           fullscreen: true,
           id: 'projForm',
           dockedItems:[
            {
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                dock: 'top',
                title: 'Project 1',
            }
           ],
           items: [
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                label: 'project_id',
                name: 'project_id'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                label: 'project_name',
                name: 'project_name'
            },
        ]
        });

     var record = projectStore.getAt(0);
     projectForm.loadRecord(record);
    }
});
```

`project.json` returns the following

```
[{"project_id": "1211", "project_name": "My test Project"}]
```

Comment: can you give me details of record.data ? does that contain values for the form fields?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be `projectForm.getForm().loadRecord(record);` instead of `projectForm.loadRecord(record);`.